# sqlite3_open не получаетсяоткрыть базу в явно указанной директории

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite, sqlite3

ОС - Windows
Кодировка входной строки - неизвестна, но скорее всего виндовская будет. 
Кодировка файлов проекта - набор символов юникода.
Язык - С++

Проблема - **не получается подключиться к базе в** иной **явно указанной** директории ("file:C:/Users/Public/Desktop/testDb.sqlite") она просто не создается...
**Однако адрес указанный относительно текущего каталога где находится программа - работает пример: ("SqLite/testDb.sqlite")**

Конструктор класса обертки который одновременно подключает к базе следующий:

```
CSqliteManager::CSqliteManager(const char* dbName)
{
    db = nullptr;
    int rc = sqlite3_open(dbName, &db);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        db = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Подскажите как изменить строку на подключение или же что либо еще так что бы ни у меня ни у других пользователей не было проблем ? Программа будет на компьютерах с Windows использоваться.

Comment: и что же говорит `sqlite3_errmsg()`, когда не получается открыть базу?

Comment: @Fat-Zer #define SQLITE_CANTOPEN    14   /* Unable to open the database file */

Comment: «`file:C:/Users/Public/Desktop/testDb.sqlite`» — слеш(и) после `file:` пропущены только здесь или в исходнике тоже? в `errno` никакой дополнительной информации нет?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я пробовал как со слешами так без них... Не как не получается. Если Вам не сложно, то запустите приложенный отрывок кода у себя, интерестно быть может это только у меня такая проблема...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Бфть может у меня проблемы с правами записи или же еще что нибуль... только я не знаю как это проверить на виндовс (да и может ли подобное быть, ведь я сижу под пользователем - Администратор)

Comment: у меня нет доступа к машине с win... так что проверить не смогу...